# Query column nullability of the resulting rowset of a tsql SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, null

Consider the following pseudo-tsql

```
table a
{
   field1 int,
   field2 int NULL
}

table b
{
   field1 int,
   field3 int
}


create procedure Sp1
As
    Select a.field1, a.field2, b.field3
    From a inner join b on a.field1 = b.field1
```

Is it possible to query the procedure Sp1 for if the resulting columns can be null or not?
It seems the dataset generator can pull that off right?

Can it be done in tsql? By other means?

---

Desired output:

```
field1 int, field2 int NULL, field3 int
```

Or:

```
field1, field2 nullable, field3
```

(The first would obviously be better)

---

Thanks!

Comment: I cant understand y our question clearly, do you mean dont show any row when a.field2 is null or not show a.field2 as null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset generator will set the [FMTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) set option on. This causes empty result sets to be returned to the client, instead of actually running the queries. Most client data access technologies (e.g. [ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx), SQL Native client, etc) have ways of interrogating result set objects (even empty ones) and determining schema information about them.

I can't think of a way to actually consume this information from T-SQL though. The only way of grabbing a result set from a stored procedure is [INSERT...EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx), but in that case, you have to already have a table defined.